# Problems with grid view in magento

Tags: magento, grid

I ussing magento and i have a problem in the grid view to add more than three products page is unconfigured

this the problem
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzM1u.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

Go to the catalog Mange category in the admin and edit it.

In custom layout update check for this line

`<reference name="product_list">
     <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>#add no that is required#</columns></action>
</reference>`

ex `<columns>#add no that is required#</columns>` if you want 4 columns add

`<columns>4</columns>`